# silverlight crashes as datagrid in edit loses focus

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

so the goes something like this: I have two datagrids for editing data. One edits an array of strings, and the second edits an array of objects that contain multiple data fields (so, a matrix of some sort, essentially).

For some reason, when I click on the first datagrid (for array of strings) to edit a particular cell, if I click somewhere else outside the datagrid (say, a button outside) to exit edit, the interface hangs, and then Chrome (or IE) crashes. Even when I run the app in debug mode in VS, no errors were thrown.

Does anyone know how to hunt this bug down?

in MainPage.xaml:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="88" Height="165" Name="ObjectsGrid" Width="196" KeyDown="ObjectsGrid_KeyDown" CellEditEnding="ObjectsGrid_CellEditEnding">
```

in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void ObjectsGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            if (ObjectsGrid.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                ArrayOfString s = (ArrayOfString)ObjectsGrid.ItemsSource;
                s.Remove((String)ObjectsGrid.SelectedItem);
                ObjectsGrid.ItemsSource = null;
                ObjectsGrid.ItemsSource = s;
            }
        }
    }

private void ObjectsGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid tGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        String c = ((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text;

        HashtableCollection[_currentCorrespondingItem].DataBoundObject[tGrid.SelectedIndex] = c;
    }
```

and this is failing.

Comment: btw - sometimes when I edit the fields, after exiting the edit mode, the entire screen just goes blank. A little information about the implementation, I implemented the CellEditEnding event on the first datagrid (with array of strings), and RowEditEnding event on the second datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it get to the HitsGrid_CellEditending?  If so, place a bracket at the { before "DataGrid tGrid" and keep pressing F11 untill you get to a error. If you get to any.  If no error raises I can only assume the action you are performing in HintsGrid_CellEditEnding clears your datagrid or even application.

Comment: I've included the code for one of the grids (the one with array of strings binded). If I try to edit any of the fields, and then click outside of the grid, silverlight crashes.

Comment: btw the break didn't work in Unhandled, the silverlight application completely hangs that it doesn't send anything back to VS :( It's bizarre and it's in both IE and Chrome.

Comment: User367696, currently at work,  tonight I will try build your project and see if I can find any more information on your error. Check back around midnight to see my progress. It helps if you can explain a little about the BopComCollection,  what is this? I can't find any information on it googling

Comment: Yo guys. I just figured it out. I changed the code above slightly so it's more obvious what these things are. What I found out is that the problem is here: HashtableCollection[_currentCorrespondingItem].DataBoundObject[tGrid.SelectedIndex] = c; ===> This line must be performed in Cell_EditEnded Event, not the Cell_EditEnding Event. I think the latter is for getting information about the edit and the former is for saving. Once I moved the "saving to data structure" line to EditEnded, everything worked! :)